# Format html code in flask?

Tags: html, flask, format, jinja2, prettify

Is it possible to format html code before I render it with flask? In my current project, I use many jinja templates and everything is working, but the source code in the browser, doesn't look so good. It's not so important but it would look much nicer with a prettified html code.
Thanks

Comment: You mean styling the html page ?

Comment: I don't mean css. I mean the real source code of the site. When you right-click on any web page, you can select "View Source Code" or something like this. In flask this code looks not so good, so I want to format the code before I render it with flask

Comment: I thought no one cares about view source code. As long as page serves it purpose better.

Comment: I know that no one cares about that. I also wrote that it is not important, but it would look nice.

Answer (score 0):

Intellij Idea understand .html files with jinja2 templates. Just use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> for make formatting of whole file.

Comment: I don't mean to format the code in the ide. The code should be formatted when it is in the web browser